# Jquery - Remove only text content from a div

Tags: jquery

is possible to remove only text content from a div, i.e. leave all other elements intact and only remove text that is directly inside a div?

Answer (score 88):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#YourDivId').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

Or using an ES6 arrow function:

```
$('#YourDivId').contents().filter((_, el) => el.nodeType === 3).remove();
```

If you want to make your code more readable and you only need to support IE9+, you can use the [node type constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType). Personally, I'd also split the filter function out and name it, for reuse and even better readability:

```
let isTextNode = (_, el) => el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;

$('#YourDivId').contents().filter(isTextNode).remove();
```

Here's a snippet with all the examples:

```js
$('#container1').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).remove();

$('#container2').contents().filter((_, el) => el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).remove();

let isTextNode = (_, el) => el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;

$('#container3').contents().filter(isTextNode).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <h1>This shouldn't be removed.</h1>
  This text should be removed.
  <p>This shouldn't be removed either.</p>
  This text should also be removed.
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <h1>This shouldn't be removed.</h1>
  This text should be removed.
  <p>This shouldn't be removed either.</p>
  This text should also be removed.
</div>

<div id="container3">
  <h1>This shouldn't be removed.</h1>
  This text should be removed.
  <p>This shouldn't be removed either.</p>
  This text should also be removed.
</div>
```

Comment: looks excellent answer but can you please explain work around? what is node type === 3 ?

Comment: @eirenaios https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: Be careful how you copy/paste, there are some weird invisible Unicode characters in this solution

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="element-to-clean">
  Content to be filtered out.
  <span class="element-to-leave-intact">
    Content to be left inthe element.
  </span>
</div>
```

You can achieve your desired behavior by using the following JavaScript + jQuery 2.1 code:

```
$('.element-to-clean').html($('.element-to-clean').children());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with simple dom:

```
var div=$("div")[0];
if(div.childNodes.length)
   for(var i=0;i<div.childNodes.length;i++)
   {
       if(div.childNodes[i].nodeType===3)
           div.removeChild(div.childNodes[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be something like this:

```
$('#div').html($('<div>').append($('*', '#div')).html());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this probably wont be the best way but i saved the div in a variable and then after i removed all the content in the tag i used append:

```
$('.wpcf7 form p').each(function(i){
    var el = $(this).find('span');
    if(i==4)
    el = $(this).find('input');
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append(el);
});
```

Answer (score -6):

```
$('#yourDiv').text('');
```

This will remove your text content

Comment: No, it removes everything inside the div.

Comment: I am late to the show, but why did Krish get -1 for this and Gary get +1.