# jquery remove all child elements and leave text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats the best way to remove all child elements from a div but leave any text that is directly inside the div in jquery.

I have tried .childre().remove() but this is adding loads of whitespace in firefox and opera.  Works fine in ie though.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div You just have to change the note type.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$('#element_id').children().remove().end().text($.trim($('#element_id').text()));
```

The `$.trim` is supposed to remove the surrounding whitespace from the text.

Comment: +1; Although you don't need the hash `#` before the `div` in the selector, but works with both: http://jsfiddle.net/NTxx7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/L6G7e/

Comment: @Giu: The hash was meant to show element id, made more meaningful name now. Thanks :)