# Counting inner text letters of HTML element

Tags: html, selenium

Is there a way to count the letters of inner text of an HTML element, without counting the letters of inner element's texts?

I tried out the ".getText()" method of "WebElements" using the Selenium library, but this counts the inner Texts of inner web elements in (e.G. "<body><div>test</div></body>" results in 4 letters for the "div" **and** the "body" element, instead of **0** for the "body" element)

Do I have to use an additional HTML parsing library, and when yes which one would you recommend?

I'm using Java 7...

Comment: I added the used language, now.

Comment: Parsing library? The elements are not in the DOM? Is it a HTML string? (I could write a solution in JavaScript, btw)

Comment: Take a look at these: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422949/jquery-remove-all-child-elements-and-leave-text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955955/get-text-of-an-element-without-children-in-javascript (there's also a solution without jQuery)

Comment: I need a java 7 solution

Comment: I'm able to get the HTML String with Selenium, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956009/1273080), I cooked you a solution:

The piece of JavaScript takes an element, iterates over all its child nodes and if they're text nodes, it reads them and returns them concatenated:

```
var element = arguments[0];
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++)
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        text += element.childNodes[i].textContent;
    }
return text;
```

I saved this script into a `script.js` file and loaded it into a single `String` via [`FileUtils.readFileToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29). You can use Guava's [`Files.toString()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), too. Or just embed it into your Java code.

```
final String script = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("script.js"), "UTF-8");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

...

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.anything("myElement"));
String text = (String)js.executeScript(script, element);
```

Comment: @TimBittersohl: *If* this has solved your problem, you can help others to know by accepting the answer.  You can do that by clicking the clear tick mark to the left of the answer, so that it turns green.  There's a lot more information about it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/159222