# Selenium - determine background-color of transparent HTML objects

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver, background-color

I want to count the number of characters with a specific background color. To realize that i walk through all the HTML-Nodes using this solution: [Counting inner text letters of HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314986/counting-inner-text-letters-of-html-element)

Html Page:

```
  <span style="background-color: #ffff00;">
    <span id="child">I inherit the background color but Selenium gives me back transparent</span>
  </span>
```

Selenium Example:

```
FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
// firefoxDriver.get(...);

WebElement element = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.id("child"));
final String cssValue = element.getCssValue("background-color");

System.out.println("TextColor of the Child Element: " + cssValue);
```

The problem is now, that the System.out prints "transparent" as css value instead of #ffff00 for background-color.

I would now need some code to look for the value of the parent, in this case. If the parent has "transparent" as value, too, then it should go on like that.

I'm using java 7, but could execute JavaScript code per Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS values don't always inherit by default. In your case the inner span does not inherit the background colour unless you tell it to specifically.

I have done up two jsFiddles to prove this:

No inherit:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLXfr/

With Inherit:
http://jsfiddle.net/B67Bm/

As you can see the value sent back is only the same as the parents background colour if you tell the child element to inherit background colour.

UPDATE:

Having looked at your added source there are a few questions you need to answer but this is possible.

This is an ugly algorithm, and I don't have selenium in front of me so you'll have to check the default values. Basic idea is run through the DOM looking at parent/grandparent/greatgrandparent until you find a parent element that has a color set and return it.

```
public String getParentBackgroundColor(WebElement element) {
    WebElement current = element;
    //Ugly while true loop, fix this
    while(true) {
        //Get the current elements parent
        WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath("..")); 

        //If the parent is null then doesn't have a parent so we should stop (change to seleniums default if element doesn't have a parent)
        if (parent == null) {
            throw new WeFailedException("Sorry, no parent elements had a background-color set");
        } else {
            //Otherwise get the parents color
            String color = parent.getCssValue("background-color");
            //If the color is transparent (based off your description, this could be some other default value) then set the parent as the current and continue the loop to try and get the parents parents color
            if (color == "transparent") {
                current = parent;
            } else {
                //If we found a color return it
                return color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use this and pass your inner span to it and it should return the parents color.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that i want to get the background color of the inner HTML-Object, although it is set to "transparent".

Comment: The background color of the inner element is transparent, as proven by my first jsFiddle. Since you haven't set it and it doesn't inherit the parents colour then it comes back as the default return type of the function you use, in jQuery this is rgba(0,0,0,0) ie an empty transparent black colour.

Comment: exactly this is my problem, i like to determine the real background color, in our case given by the parent, using Selenium

Comment: I don't think you understand html and css very well. Do you mean you want to find the background colour of the actual rendered pixels that make up the area the inner object contains on the page? As this is pretty much impossible. An easy fix is add span { background-color:inherit; } to your css (forcing all spans to inherit their parents background color unless overridden in style) so as in my second fiddle it will return the value you want.

Comment: i want the count of text with an specific background color. even if it is some inner element.

Comment: just add span { background-color:inherit; } to your css. Thats the easiest way. Edit your question to explain why you are doing this, what you have tried, some sample code in the language you are using, a sample page (jsFiddle link). Otherwise it is very hard to help you

Comment: Also remove that downvote or I won't help any further. I will try to help you if you play nice and remove the downvote. Thanks

Comment: i haven't voted down you, really. I'm new and i have only eight reputation points, as you see. But i would love to give you a check

Comment: must have been someone else. Updated with a suggested solution, pretty rough but should help.