# Python Selenium .value_of_css_property("background-color") returns black (0.0,0.0,0.0) for all tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium in my python code to loop through all elements in html page and retrieve their text color and background-color with **element.value_of_css_property("color")** and **element.value_of_css_property("background-color")** functions. It properly returns me the text color but the background color always returns me black (0.0,0.0,0.0).

Below is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Initialize webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to webpage
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

# Find all elements on the page
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")

# Iterate through elements and check color contrast
for element in elements:
    color = element.value_of_css_property("color")
    bg_color = element.value_of_css_property("background-color")
    print(color)
    print(bg_color)
```

Any thoughts on why it always returns black as a background color and how can I fix it?

Comment: what happens if you run `Color.from_string(bg_color).hex` with `from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color`?

Comment: try here https://dev.to/pavel_polivka/determining-the-effective-background-color-17ld and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413575/selenium-determine-background-color-of-transparent-html-objects

Comment: It seems the first solution partially solves my problem)) thank you! the problem is that it's very resource intensive. for each tag it can go back up to the body tag.. (big(O) ~ n square.) .. But for now I think this is the best what we have )) thank again!