# jQuery — Remove unwrapped text but preserve the elements?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

So here's the code:

```
<parent><child>i want to keep the child</child>Some text I want to remove</parent>
```

I'd like to change it to this:

```
<parent><child>i want to keep the child</child></parent>
```

I see lots of people asking how to remove the child element and preserve the unwrapped text, but not the other way around. How do you target something that isn't named?

Comment: So you want to delete text not wrapped inside another element from the parent element? How do you tell which elements you want to do this to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Remove only text content from a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div) and [several of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+remove+text+leave+children)

Comment: @Felix read the question the OP wants to remove the div from the div, not the text

Comment: @Neal: Which question are you talking about? The one I linked to? It is the same question.

Comment: @Felix the question the OP referred to is the question you said was a dupe. the OP does not want to do that

Comment: @Neal: I'm confused. This question is about removing the text that is directly in `parent`. The question I linked to is about the same problem. I mean, the title is *Remove only text content from a div* and I tried the code in the answer, it works.

Comment: @Felix, read the question. the op does **not** want the text. the OP wants to ignore the text and get the div contained within

Comment: @Neal: The question is: *is possible to remove only text content from a div, i.e. leave all other elements intact and only remove text that is directly inside a div?* That is exactly what this question is about. Nothing about retrieving elements. Removing text! And if you have a look at the highest voted answer, this is exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: @Neal @Felix either way, Neals solution is pretty elegant, if it's for a simple text removal at least, and it wasnt given in those other posts. I dont know why those posts didnt show up when i started writing this question, i think this question has a more searchable title anyhow.

Comment: @Felix see above. and thanks ^_^ wasnt trying to argue. just wasnt being understood :-)

Comment: @RGBK: I'm not saying anything against @Neal's answer. Just saying that the other question is about the same problem. No hard feelings :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
var child = $('parent').children('child');

$('parent').html(child);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/t2CDk/

if you do this you lose any `event listeners` and data from the elements.

Comment: The problem with `html` is that it will remove event listeners and `data` from the elements. This might or might not be a problem, but it has to be said.

Comment: You can preserve events too: `var child = $('parent').children('child').clone(true);` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t2CDk/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the ol' fashioned javascript way, and test each node for the nodeType of 3, then do a removeChild on it.  This would be pretty clean and quick (minimal jQuery), and wouldn't mess up any event listeners.

```
var parent = $('parent')[0];  // Get reference to DOM

for( var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
  var current_child = parent.childNodes[i];
  if( current_child.nodeType == 3 )
    parent.removeChild( current_child );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified Neals answer so it works for multiple elements:

```
$( elements ).each(function() {  
var child = $(this).children();  
$(this).html(child);   
});
```

Comment: The original already accomplishes this; jQuery automatically manages this for us. See http://jsfiddle.net/t2CDk/9/

Answer (score 0):

Very simple just use this code:

```
jQuery(function($){

    // Replace 'td' with your html tag
    $("td").html(function() { 

    // Replace 'ok' with string you want to change, you can delete 'hello everyone' to remove the text
          return $(this).html().replace("ok", "hello everyone");  

    });
});
```

Here is full example: https://blog.hfarazm.com/remove-unwrapped-text-jquery/