# Change text node whose siblings are tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my html:

```
<div id="ref">
   <p>.....</p>
   <p>.....</p>
   abcd
</div>
```

I want to change "abcd" text to some other text say "wxyz".
How can I traverse to that text particularly in jquery?

#### Edit 1:

I am asking this question in general terms, It is not necessary that it is always "abcd" or "wxyz"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div might help man!

Comment: Thanks man for your all time support, Esailija answer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#ref").contents().last()[0].nodeValue = "wyxz";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rWss5/

Comment: He said `wxyz`, not `wyxz`.  Sheesh! :P

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(function(){
    var text = $('#ref').text();
    text = text.replace("abcd", "wxyz");
    $('#ref').text(text);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2saH/

Comment: This removes the paragraph elements