# Jquery remove the innertext but preserve the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have something like this.

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</div>
```

I want to remove '**This is some text**' and need the html elements intact.

I tried using something like

```
$("#firstDiv")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text("");
```

But it didn't work.

Is there a way to get (and possibly remove, via something like `.text(""))` just the free text within a tag, and not the text within its child tags?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4399718/2524304

Comment: instead of .text(), can try .val('')?

Comment: @Happycoder still its not working :(

Comment: To point out the problem in your code - you are cloning the element (which will create a new independant element) at first and then you do the operations on the clone, which will not affect the original element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Remove only text content from a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2CDk/11/)

Suppose you have this html

```
<parent>
  <child>i want to keep the child</child>
  Some text I want to remove
  <child>i want to keep the child</child>
  <child>i want to keep the child</child>
</parent>
```

Then you can remove the parent's inner text like this:

```
var child = $('parent').children('child');
$('parent').html(child);
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2CDk/12/) for a solution to your html

```
var child = $('#firstDiv').children('span');
$('#firstDiv').html(child);
```

PS: Be aware that any event handlers bounded on that div will be lost as you delete and then recreate the elements

Comment: At the same time you're creating all the elements again, so all data, event handlers etc. will be lost.

Answer (score 7):

Filter out text nodes and remove them:

```
$('#firstDiv').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType===3;
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zJFrD/1/)

To also filter on the text itself, you can do:

```
$('#firstDiv').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() === 'This is some text';
}).remove();
```

and to get the text :

```
var txt = [];

$('#firstDiv').contents().filter(function() {
    if ( this.nodeType === 3 ) txt.push(this.nodeValue);
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

Comment: It can be any where in that div

Answer (score 2):

Why try to force jQuery to do it when it's simpler with vanilla JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('firstDiv'),
    i,
    el;

for (i = 0; i< div.childNodes.length; i++) {
    el = div.childNodes[i];
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
        div.removeChild(el);
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YPKGQ/

Comment: I wouldn't say it's simpler (if you look at adeneo's `.filter` solution, it's just less code to write), but it's definitely not very difficult either.

Comment: @FelixKling - That's very true. But it is much simpler than some of the jQuery solutions posted!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, not sure if it does what you want exactly... Note: i only tested it in chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/LgyJ8/

```
cleartext($('#firstDiv'));

function cleartext(node) {

    var children = $(node).children();
    if(children.length > 0) {

        var newhtml = "";
        children.each(function() {

            cleartext($(this));

            newhtml += $('<div/>').append(this).html();

        });

        $(node).html(newhtml);

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with `.html` (and `.innerHTML`) is that the browser as to parse the HTML string and creates new elements from it. That's ok if you are with new elements. But if you converted existing elements to HTML and then set the HTML to "recreate" those elements, you will loose all event handlers and data bound to those elements.

Comment: Well it's not the perfect solution of course, but since the OP didn't mention binding events to these BEFORE the stripping, i figured it was worthy of a jsfiddle to see if the idea that popped into my head would work.