# Jquery does not remove all content as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code on my web page.

```
<div id="phoneDiv">+7 (999) 999-9999
    <div class="editmode">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" value="+7 (999) 999-9999" id="editPhone" name="editPhone" class="text key">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to remove just the text without removing of `div.editmode`.

I used the function:

```
$(document).on('click','#phoneDiv',function(){
$("#phoneDiv").not('div.editmode, div.editmode *').remove();
});
```

but it just removes all the content.

Why is this not working? Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftngmx4j/)

Comment: See this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that's not how you should use `.not()`. It is used to filter the elements in the actual JQuery object you're dealing with (in your case, you're selecting `#phoneDiv`), not its children...

But, to remove the text, you'd need to target it in a different way, since it is not actualy an element. You can get it through `.contents()`. Filter it to exclude the div element, and then perform the `.remove()`

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftngmx4j/2/)

```js
$(document).on('click','#phoneDiv',function(){
    $("#phoneDiv").contents().filter(function() {
        return (!$(this).is(".editmode"));
    }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phoneDiv">+7 (999) 999-9999
    <div class="editmode">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" value="+7 (999) 999-9999" id="editPhone" name="editPhone" class="text key" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just removed the whole `#phoneDiv`, including all its children.

Instead, wrap the text in a class like this:

```
<div class="number">
    +7 (999) 999-9999
</div>
```

Then remove or hide the number only

```
$(".number").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply set that Skype telephone into a `div` or `span` with a class and erase its content?

```
<div id="phoneDiv">
    <div class="js-erase-me">+7 (999) 999-9999</div>
    <div class="editmode">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" value="+7 (999) 999-9999" id="editPhone" name="editPhone" class="text key">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the function:

```
$(document).on('click','#phoneDiv',function(){
    $(".js-erase-me").html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/ftngmx4j/1/

The jQuery not() function sees for elements that match the first selector but not the second selector. i.e.

```
$("#phoneDiv").not('div.editmode, div.editmode *')
```

matches div with id="phoneDiv" but class !="editmode". You need to use:

```
$("#phoneDiv").children().not('div.editmode').remove();
```

Also see I have added a span tag to the HTML. That is for jQuery to include it in children()