# Inserting text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

It's continue of [Jquery does not remove all content as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430394/jquery-not-removes-all-content/27430526#27430526) question. 
I want now to insert text from the input before it now. This is what I've done.

```
$(document).on('click','#phoneDiv',function(){
    phone=$("#editPhone").val();
    $("#phoneDiv").contents().filter(function() {
        return (!$(this).is(".editmode"));
    }).remove();
    $('div#editPhone').prepend(document.createTextNode(phone));
});
```

And here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftngmx4j/4/) of course. It just removes text but doesn't inserts value.

Comment: Is there any reason you're mixing up `jQuery` and `Vanilla Javascript`? I suggest that you choose one and stick to it.

Comment: to expand on @MelanciaUK's point, pick one for **DOM manipulation** and stick with it.

Comment: Use `var` when declaring variables, unless you've declared it globally elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You don't actually need all that code using `.filter()` or either `.contents()`. A simple `.children()` would do it.

Comment: Within the `click event` handler, you can refer to `$("#phoneDiv")` by just `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're removing the `phonediv` contents. so `div#editPhone` (a child of `phonediv`) doesn't exist when you try to prepend to it.

```
$(document).on('click','#phoneDiv',function(){
    var phone=$("#editPhone").val();
    $("#phoneDiv").contents().filter(function() {
        return (!$(this).is(".editmode"));
    }).remove();
    $('div#phoneDiv').prepend(phone); //<-- div#editPhone doesn't exist anymore, you removed it above
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/ftngmx4j/5/