# How to empty value of td without delete input that Embedded in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want delete value of a custom td.

```html
<td> <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="1"> some text </td>
```

I don't want delete input and want delete some text only.any help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div

Answer (score 1):

Then only update the `textContent` by invoking `text` method

For example,

```js
//$("td").text(""); //Doesn't work

//$("td")[0].textContent = ""; //Doesn't work

//convert childNodes to Array and then iterate through the same
Array.prototype.slice.call( $("td")[0].childNodes ).forEach(function(node){
  node.nodeType == 3 && node.parentNode.removeChild(node); //if the node is a text node then remove the same
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="1">some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @MohsenZahedi please check now

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla solution

```js
var td = document.querySelector('td'),
    child = td.childNodes
    
for (var i = 0;i < child.length;i++){
  if (child[i].nodeType === 3){
    td.removeChild(child[i])
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<td> <input type="text" name="myinput" value="1"> some text </td>
</table>
```