# How to replace text of element that isn't tagged

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML.

```
<td>
    Line 1
    <div id="foobar">Foobar</div>
</td>
```

How can I change Line 1 to say Line 2 without replacing/overwriting the `#foobar` element?

Comment: See [older post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div) for solution to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery **[`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)** method like following.

```js
var div = $('#foobar').detach();
$('td').html(div).prepend('Line 2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Line 1
            <div id="foobar">Foobar</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var abcd= document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var newabcd = abcd.childNodes[0];
newText.nodeValue = 'Line 2 ';


<td>
      Line 1
      <div id="foobar">Foobar</div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly edit the content of your `<td></td>` tag. Two solutions:

1 wrap your Line 1 with a `<span></span>` or `<p></p>` tag to identify it
2 extract the whole content of your `<td></td>` and use a regular expression to extract your div from it and merge it with your new text.

Answer (score 0):

with this first extract the content of the tag  `<span>`  then you can rewrite the parent tag of  `<span>`  and append the first value, and if you want trigger this from a button simple add `onclick="replace_content()"` to your button or link

```
function replace_content(){
    var foo=$("#foobar").html();
    $("#foobar").parent().html("Line 2"+foo);
}
```

```js
    function replace_content(){
        var foo=$("#foobar").html();
        $("#foobar").parent().html("Line 2 "+foo);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
      Line 1
      <div id="foobar">Foobar</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<button onclick="replace_content()">change text</button>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: thanks... I was very busy when I write the first answer