# Dynamically removing text inside a element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="some-class">
    Some Text Here
    <ul>
        <li class="another-class"> Main Content </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to know how to **remove** the text "*Some Text Here*" using **jQuery**... 
 So I will get:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <ul>
        <li class="another-class"> Main Content </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Do you have control over the output of that div? Why not wrap it in a `<span>` and target it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Remove only text content from a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div)

Comment: I don't have control... I can select what I want... but I just want to delete what I don't want instead...

Comment: When would you even have this use case? how are you getting the data? or will the text be static

Comment: The solution that @Sphinx shared worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @TomaszBubała seriously?

Comment: Yes, seriously. If you provided any code showing you tried anything, people wouldn't downvote your question. All you've said is "i want to get this done and i want to get it done with jQuery".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is looking for the `textNodes` using the attribute [`noteType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType):

```js
function isTextElement() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}

$('.some-class').contents().filter(isTextElement).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
  Some Text Here
  <ul>
    <li class="another-class"> Main Content </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $elements = $('.some-class > *').detach()
$('.some-class').empty().append($elements)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsq0fzxu/2/

Specific to the code sample above.

Takes all direct elements under div.some-class,
deletes free floating texts, append elements back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[contents()][1]` of jQuery and then apply filter on nodeType = 3 as nodeType.TextNode value is `3`.

For more info on `nodeType` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

```js
$('.some-class').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
  Some Text Here
  <ul>
   <li class="another-class"> Main Content </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove text,then you can do empty li text

```
$('.another-class').text('');
```

if you want to remove li element,that have text then apply class selector in your case and use remove method of jquery

```
$('.another-class').remove();
```