# Remove text from a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for a way to remove a text from a div, without removing the button inside.
Please see the image above.

The following code does not work because it removes the button too.

```
$(".input-group-append").empty();
```

OR

```
document.querySelector(".input-group-append").text = '';
document.querySelector(".input-group-append").innerHTML = '';
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery - Remove only text content from a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div)

Comment: @ack no  :( :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the text, you can store the children selectors first and clear the parent with `innerHTML=''` and add that children selectors again.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".input-group-append");
const childs = [];
for(let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i ++) {
  childs.push(parent.children[i]);
}

parent.innerHTML = '';
childs.forEach((item) => parent.appendChild(item));
```

```html
<div class="input-group-append">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search">Submit Button</button>
  Test Text
</div>
```

Comment: can you please give another version of `childs.forEach((item) => parent.appendChild(item));` because it Es5, and it does'nt work in my gulp ES5 ? i think i should make a normal function not an arrow

Comment: You can use `for` loop like. `for (let i = 0; i < childs.length; i ++) { parent.appendChild(childs[i]); }`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not planning to remove the button itself and just want to remove the text within the button, you must modify the seclector to direct towards the button itself and then use `text` or `innerText` property.

```
document.querySelector(".input-group-append > button").text = '';

// OR

document.querySelector(".input-group-append > button").innerText = '';
```

This will remove the text from within the button.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case could probably just do,

```
el = document.querySelector('.input-group-append')
for (let i = 0;i<el.children.length;i++) {
  if(el.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
    el.removeChild(el.childNodes[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: i had this : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

This shoud remove all loose text from your div without touching elements:

```
var elements = $(".input-group-append *");
$(".input-group-append").html("");
elements.each(function(){
  $(".input-group-append").append($(this)[0]);
});
```

Comment: it remove the button too