# How to clear text only not others element clear by jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".final-step").text(" ");
});
```

```html
 <div class="final-step">i will be remove only <span class="">i will not remove</span> <i class="">me too</i></div>
```

i try this but it remove all element

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421999/jquery-remove-only-text-content-from-a-div/3422046) help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on a pure JS

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("final-step")[0]
let childNodes = element.childNodes
for (let node of childNodes){
    if (node.nodeName == '#text'){
        document.getElementsByClassName("final-step")[0].removeChild(node)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in JQuery. Is it what you needed?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var text = $('.final-step span').text();
   $(".final-step").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="final-step">i will be remove only <span class="">i will not remove</span> <i class="">me too</i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This May Be This Will Help You

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var f = $(".final-step").html();
   var h = $(".final-step").contents().first();
   var g = f.replace(h.text(), "");
   $(".final-step").html(g)
});
```

```html
<div class="final-step">i will be remove only <span class="">i will not remove</span> <i class="">me too</i></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```